# UIImagePickerController crashes with LongPressGesture

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Today I realized that my UIImagePickerController is working fine when I use it with a button to present it. However, when I want to present it via LongPressGesture, the app crashes on runtime. Why so?

Action:

```
@IBAction func ppLongPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.profileImage.image = image

    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long gesture has states

```
@IBAction func ppLongPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state != .began { return }
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```